# Cat can not get the content with pipe?

Tags: shell

there is a file named test , there is only one line on test ,`haha`

```
tiger@debian:~$ cat test
haha
tiger@debian:~$ cat 'test'
haha
```

Why the following command can not get `haha`?the  `ls test` output `test`,why ls test | cat  can not output `haha`?

```
tiger@debian:~$ ls test
test
ls test  | cat 
test
```

my system is debian+bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at 'man cat'

When using 
`cat test` or `cat 'test'`, the shell assumes that the second argument is always a file name.

However, with pipeline, cat expects to get a bunch of text, therefore, the content of 'ls' is printed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the pipe itself, it's that `ls test` doesn't output the content of the file `test`. `ls` lists the directory contents. `ls test` will simply output `test`.

If you absolutely wish to use pipe to display the content of `test` you can use:

```
cat test | xargs echo
```

Comment: If you absolutely wish to use pipe to display the content of `test`, you should reconsider what you're doing. If all you want to do is print the contents of a file, there's no reason to use a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to display the content of the file like that, try

```
ls test | xargs cat
```